# Day has multiple time so need to combine multiple time by day?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have situation like below output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => Monday
            [start_time] => 10:30
            [end_time] => 13:30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => Monday
            [start_time] => 17:30
            [end_time] => 19:30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => Tuesday
            [start_time] => 10:30
            [end_time] => 13:30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => Tuesday
            [start_time] => 17:30
            [end_time] => 19:30
        )
)
```

What i need is while displaying data it should display like below format

```
Monday - 10:30 - 13:30 , 17:30 - 19:30

Tueday - 10:30 - 13:30 , 17:30 - 19:30
```

But what i get is like this

```
Monday - 10:30 - 13:30

Monday - 17:30 - 19:30

Tuesday - 10:30 - 13:30

Tuesday - 17:30 - 19:30

$data['date']= $this->my_model->gettime($hid,$did); // Controller code.
```

This is query :

`SELECT day , start_time , end_time FROM date WHERE id='$hid' AND id2='$did'`

This is php code :

```
<?php 
        foreach ($date as $k => $v){ 
        echo "<li>".$v['day']." -    ".$v['start_time']." - ".$v['end_time']."</li>"; 
        } ?>
```

// View code
Please help me with this ..........

Thanks is advance

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to help with _specific issues_ you encounter _in your own code_. So start out yourself, if you run into serious issues, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and point out that issue you ran into.

Comment: I have tried to unique , distinct in sql but i only get the one row

Comment: How are you filling your array? From DB or from variable?

Comment: using variable which i got in responce from DB

Comment: Then you had better show us the code that gets the data

Comment: #arkascha so you mean this is not a issue right . So what do mean by issue. If it is a easy task for you then solve it. You will be proven as a genious.

Comment: Please post that in YOUR QUESTION using the EDIT link. Nobody can read code posted in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try before asking.Do some google you will get many related answer.

try like this:

```
$arr=array( 
array(
        'day' => 'Monday',
        'start_time' => '17:30',
        'end_time' => '19:30'
),
 Array
(
        'day' => 'Tuesday',
        'start_time' => '10:30',
        'end_time' => '13:30'
),
 Array
(
        'day' => 'Tuesday',
        'start_time' => '17:30',
        'end_time' => '19:30'
),
 Array
(
        'day' => 'Wednesday',
        'start_time' => '10:30',
        'end_time' => '13:30'
)
, Array
(
        'day' => 'Wednesday',
        'start_time' => '17:30',
        'end_time' => '19:30'
)

);

$result=array();


foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($result[$value['day']])){
        $result[$value['day']]=$result[$value['day']]."  , ".$value['start_time']."-".$value['end_time'];
    }else{
        $result[$value['day']]=$value['start_time']."-".$value['end_time'];
    }

}
//display....
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    echo $key." - ".$value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Well the OP finally got someone to do their work for them. I do hope they bother to accept your answer, but in case they dont, here is an UV

Comment: #Suchit Thanks for your help. Actually i tried to find my answer but could not get it. Will remember your suggestion.